# Is it possible to do this shape CSS?

Tags: css, gradient, css-shapes, gradient-descent

I was asked with making such a background on a responsive site. I thought about preparing two divs using gradient, but it is highly problematic. Is it even possible to do it? Using this as a background-image is cumbersome for higher and lower resolutions.

Any ideas?

[image: shape to do]

Comment: You maybe can make this preferable an svg so you can scale it properly and more easily. Else you may be able to pull this off with just css. Make a container with position relative and padding bottom trick so you can scale it with window width and then add shapes with gradients. You may have to add some white shapes on top of the gradient shapes. Good luck!

Comment: This might be able to be done with CSS clip-path to make some gradient shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

some clip-path and pseudo element can approximate this:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  aspect-ratio: .8;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0;
}

.box:before {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 50%, 10% 100%,0 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #3185c5, #0ea1b1);
}

.box:after {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 30%, 100% 50%, 10% 100%,0% 100%, 0 80%);
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #3185c5, #f55778);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```